# Compare two plists and update data in one of them

Tags: ios, compare, plist

I have a conference app with events on certain days. In my app, I can update a plist on my webserver and serve up the new data on the phone in a tableview -- works great. My users can save the item for that day to their "agenda" which populates a separate plist on the phone -- that works perfectly too.

Problem is: When I update the plist on the web, I can't figure out how to programmatically save over the phone's agenda plist which was saved by the user. Example: Three events on one day (web version) and the user has one event saved in their agenda. How do I take the new downloaded plist, find the event that they saved and overwrite that event's data?

Any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
Hobnob

Comment: So the user agenda isn't just the event identity? Or you're changing the identities on the server? Give some details of the data you're trying to merge.

Comment: I have a dictionary that contains the classID, time, room, className, date, instructor, etc. The class information is updated from a plist on my webserver. When the user hits "add to my agenda" that data gets saved to a new "agenda" plist on their device using the same dictionary structure. They can add other events and delete them as they wish. They view the "agenda" plist in another tableview. 

So... When I load the agenda tableview, I can fetch both plists, but how do I compare the two dictionaries from both plists and replace items in their agenda with the new information?